# Итератор следующий за последним

Tags: c++, итераторы

Известно что метод **end()** возвращает итератор следующий за последним, как может быть за последнем итератором еще один итератор ведь последний итератор последний.

Comment: итератор, указывающий на место, следующий за последным элементом, а не итератор, следующим за последным итератором

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Представьте массив, скажем,

```
int a[5];
```

Вот этот `end()` -  это *указатель* на элемент, следующий за последним - на `a[5]`. Реально его нет, вы не имеете права к нему обращаться...

Но можете использовать его для ограничений цикла - типа

```
for(int* i = a; i != a+5; ++i) ...
```

И не более того. Но *обращаться с помощью такого итератора к элементу нельзя!*

Answer (score 1):

В футболе это место за линией. Когда мяч пересекает линию, игра должна возобновляться с новыми условиями. В символьных массивах это символ `'\0'`, ну и т.д...  `X.end()`, Это итератор обьекта `Х`, имеющий адрес места сразу за пределом обьекта, чтобы было легче выражаться, что "поле закончилось".